# Question about the usage of "watashi"

Tags: translation, usage, definitions

I am currently slightly confused about the exact usage of the word "watashi". I know that the word means I, but it's usage seems unclear to me. Some sources say that it is simply for [polite use](http://www.jref.com/japanese/personal-possessive-pronouns/), while other sources state that it is only for [feminine use](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20130329212943AAuM18q).

Can someone clarify this pronouns usage for me?

Comment: Very strong men use 私 like Vega. https://twitter.com/vegabot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's for polite use by both genders, and the most generally used first-person pronoun. While it used to be more for women, this is no longer the case.

It is true that women tend to use わたし (*watashi*) more than other pronouns, but it is not a feminine pronoun<sup>†</sup>, and it is frequently used by men. It is more polite than others and also used more generally. Typically, it is thought of as the first-person pronoun "safest" to use as a learner.

A useful quote from the Japanese Wikipedia article (linked below):

> 現在では男女ともに使用する。
>   Nowadays men and women both use it.

More gender-locked (but not exclusively so) personal pronouns would be ぼく (*boku*) and おれ (*ore*) for men, and あたし (*atashi*) for women. **I would caution against using these, however**, until you are more comfortable with the language, since they are a bit less flexible with the situations in which they can be used.

The answer given by that *Yahoo! Answers* post has four downvotes for a reason—its writer is a junior Japanese learner and does not seem to clearly know the difference. There's honestly [lots of resources](https://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=usage+of+watashi) out there that talk about first-person pronouns in Japanese; avoid *Yahoo! Answers* whenever possible.

---

Here are a few resources on personal pronouns that are pretty accurate:

- [How to call yourself in Japanese?](http://cotoacademy.com/blog/japanese-study/how-to-call-yourself-in-japanese-boku-ore-watashi/)
- [Japanese pronouns - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Japanese_pronouns#List_of_Japanese_personal_pronouns) ([日本語](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E6%97%A5%E6%9C%AC%E8%AA%9E%E3%81%AE%E4%B8%80%E4%BA%BA%E7%A7%B0%E4%BB%A3%E5%90%8D%E8%A9%9E#.E4.B8.80.E4.BA.BA.E7.A7.B0.E5.8D.98.E6.95.B0.E4.BB.A3.E5.90.8D.E8.A9.9E.E3.81.AE.E4.B8.80.E8.A6.A7))
- [Should I use ORE, BOKU, WATASHI or something else when referring to myself?](http://www.yesjapan.com/YJ6/question/4023/should-i-use-ore_boku_watashi-or-something-else-when-referring-to-myself) <sub>(George is a very knowledgeable member of this site)</sub>

<sub><sup>†</sup> It *can* be perceived as feminine if used in casual contexts.</sub>

---

<sub>Just a note: When saying something like "thanks in advance", it's better to say よろしくおねがいします (*yoroshiku onegaishimasu*) than ありがとう.</sub>

Comment: Thank you very much for the abundance of resources, corrections and tips! 
As a little side note: I am currently using Rosetta Stone as my main resource to learn the language, I believe it will teach me the basics of the language but a consistent problem I run across are the lack of explanations. Therefore, I use the internet (mainly this site and Google searches) to clear any confusions I have, like the usage of the words desu, watashi, imasu, boku, etc.
(Thanks for the additional note as well)

Comment: That wiki's explanation for わたし "Nowadays ...." is a kind of misleading, actually, all pronouns currently used were originally gender-free and only region-specific, and after modernization and domestic migration to Tokyo, have become gender-specific in New Tokyo dialect.

Comment: +1 for よろしくおねがいします :)